# Declaring variable at the very beginning

Tags: pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading

I have a general problem in Pine script. I do not know how to declare a variable at the very beginning of a strategy and update it with every candle. When you declare it, then it will be declared at every candle!

The logic should be like this:

If a certain event happens, the variable value shall be set to x. The variable shall stay x until another event happens.

The problem that I see is, that the variable will always be reset to its origin value due to the declaraction at the beginning of the script.

my (example) code:

```
    a = 20 

    if crossover(ma1, ma2)
         a:=30
    
    if crossunder(ma1, ma2)
         a:=40
```

The variable "a" will just be 30 or 40 for the candles that trigger the ma crossover/under, but i want the value to be 30 from the crossover until the crossunder.

PS: It is not strictly necessary that the variable keeps its value. I just need the information "the last cross of the moving averages was a crossover" (respectively a crossunder).

PPS: I know that you could simply use ma1 > ma2 in this case, but this is just an example to explain my problem.

Thank you guys!
BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use var. Example:

```
var a = 0
a:=valuewhen(crossover(ma1, ma2), close, 1)
```

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html